# Coding `While` loops

Tags: infinite-loop

I am interested in replicating the code in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025041/list-of-powers-of-natural-numbers/) on MSE, whose contents I have copied for ease of reading:

**Pseudocode:** 
*Consider that 1 is the starting index of a list*
**1.**  input natural number n.
**2.**  let s = list of all natural numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ...}
**3.**  while (n>1) do
    **3.1.**  drop each n-th elementh from s 
    **3.2.**  for int i = 2 to ∞ do s[i] += s[i-1] 
    **3.3.**  n = n-1 
**4.**  Now s = {1<sup>n</sup>, 2<sup>n</sup>, 3<sup>n</sup>, 4<sup>n</sup> ...}

Example:
n = 3
s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...}

perform 3.1:  s = {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16...} 
perform 3.2:  s = {1, 3, 7, 12, 19, 27, 37, 48, 61, 75, 91 ...} 
perform 3.3:  n = 2 > 1

perform 3.1:  s = {1, 7, 19, 37, 61, 91 ...} 
perform 3.2:  s = {1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216 ...} 
perform 3.3:  n = 1 => end of while loop

The final state of s is {1<sup>3</sup>, 2<sup>3</sup>, 3<sup>3</sup>, 4<sup>3</sup>, 5<sup>3</sup> ...}

---

My interpretation of it is

```
fn[nu_][{o_, a_}] := {# - 1, Delete[a, #]} &@Mod[nu + o, Length@a, 1]
ff[n_, w_] := Last@NestList[fn[n], {0, w}, Floor[Length@w/n]][[All, 2]]
f1[l_] := Table[Total[Take[l, a]], {a, 1, Length@l}]
```

setting range=$n^2$

```
n = 4; list = Range@(n^2);
NestList[{#[[1]] - 1, f1[ff[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]} &, {n, list}, n - 1][[All, 2]] 
// ColumnForm
```

but my question is, how would this be written in *Mathematica* in the form of the pseudocode given by John_devou in the original question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
f[n_] := Module[{s, i},
  i = n;
  s = Range[1000];
  While[i > 1,
   s = Drop[s, {i, Length@s, i}];
   s = Accumulate@s;
   i--;
   ];
  s
  ]

f[3]
```

> `{1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343,...}`

If I was trying to leverage *Mathematica* I might have written:

```
s = Range[1000];
n = 3;
Fold[Accumulate@Drop[#, {#2, Length@#, #2}] &, s, Reverse@Rest@Range@n]
```

Comment: is it possible to display the loop stages with both of these methods, as given in the `NestList` example in the question?

Comment: @martin Sure, you can `Sow` the information you want to save in the `While` loop for example. In the latter solution you can also use `Sow`, or if you don't need the intermediate step 3.1 you may simply change `Fold` to `FoldList`.

Comment: great - thak you for your help :)